# How to style for last of class?

Tags: jquery, css

For example I have HTML like:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="classme"></div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="classme"></div>
  <div class="classme"></div>
  <div class="classme"></div>
</div>
```

How can style for last class is `classme`. Thank you.

Comment: what do you really want.. style if the last class is classme or style the last classme element in the outer element

Comment: for last class is classme only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following CSS2 selectors:

```
div + .classme:last-child { ... }
```

It selects `.classme` elements that are the last child of their parent and immediately preceded by a `div`. This ensures that the element has at at least one previous sibling i.e. it is not the only child.

You can also use the following CSS3 selector:

```
.classme:last-child:not(:only-child) { ... }
```

**Original answer**

You can use this:

```
.classme:last-child { ... }
```

It selects `.classme` elements that are the last child of their parent.

Answer (score 1):

You should apply the following:

```
 .other div:last-child {
    ...
  }
```

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/8LJER/

Answer (score 1):

you can do using css

```
.classme:last-child
{
    color: red;
}
```

or
 using jQuery

```
$('.classme:last-child').css('color','red')
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pk2Ay/)